# Need to get the mismatcted cells in specific partition

Tags: sql, oracle, join, row, where-clause

| ID | TC_No | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tc_1 | PASS |
| 1 | tc_2 | PASS |
| 1 | tc_3 | FAIL |
| 1 | tc_4 | PASS |
| 1 | tc_5 | FAIL |
| 2 | tc_1 | FAIL |
| 2 | tc_2 | PASS |
| 2 | tc_3 | FAIL |
| 2 | tc_4 | FAIL |
| 2 | tc_5 | FAIL |

I'm trying to find all records that have conflicting "*Result*" on the same "*TC_No*" and among different "*ID*" values, filtered by `ID IN (1,2)`.

Here's the expected output:

| ID | TC_No | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tc_1 | PASS |
| 1 | tc_4 | PASS |
| 2 | tc_1 | FAIL |
| 2 | tc_4 | FAIL |

and my attempted query:

```
SELECT * From
(SELECT * from Excel As T1
UNION 
SELECT * from Excel As T2)
As c
where ID in(1,2) order By TC_NO
```

Comment: Are mismatches always with different `ID` values?

Answer (score 0):

find the distinct count of result for each tc_no and then select the records having count greater than 1

**Query**

```
select * from your_tbl_name a
where exists(
  select 1 from (
    select tc_no, count(distinct result) as cnt
    from your_tbl_name 
    where result in ('PASS','FAIL')
    group by c_no
  ) b
  where a.tc_no = b.tc_no
  and b.cnt > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `INNER JOIN` the table onto itself and add a predicate in the `WHERE` clause to return only mismatched results.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 
  a.ID, 
  a.TC_No, 
  a.Result 
FROM 
  Excel a 
  INNER JOIN Excel b ON a.TC_No = b.TC_No 
WHERE 
  a.Result <> b.Result;
```

**Result:**

```
| ID | TC_No | Result |
|----|-------|--------|
|  1 |  tc_1 |   PASS |
|  1 |  tc_4 |   PASS |
|  2 |  tc_1 |   FAIL |
|  2 |  tc_4 |   FAIL |
```

**SQL Fiddle Demo:**
[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a3958/3)

Answer (score 0):

Check when the maximum result is different than the minimum one, in your filtered data, using window functions.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT tab.*, 
           MAX(Result_) OVER(PARTITION BY TC_No) AS max_result,
           MIN(Result_) OVER(PARTITION BY TC_No) AS min_result
    FROM tab
    WHERE ID IN (1,2)
)
SELECT Id, Tc_No, Result_
FROM cte
WHERE min_result < max_result
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2vViu5wE).

Comment: You can order the results using `ORDER BY ID, TC_No`, but it's not strictly needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use analytic function COUNT() OVER() to find the rows with different content and then just filter the result in Where clause:

```sql
SELECT  ID, TC_NO, RESULT
FROM    ( Select  ID, TC_NO, RESULT, 
                  CASE  WHEN Count(DISTINCT RESULT) OVER(Partition By TC_NO) = 2 THEN 'Y' END "IS_DIFF" 
          From    tbl
        )
WHERE IS_DIFF = 'Y'
ORDER BY ID
```

With your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl (ID, TC_NO, RESULT) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'tc_1', 'PASS' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'tc_2', 'PASS' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'tc_3', 'FAIL' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'tc_4', 'PASS' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'tc_5', 'FAIL' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'tc_1', 'FAIL' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'tc_2', 'PASS' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'tc_3', 'FAIL' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'tc_4', 'FAIL' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'tc_5', 'FAIL' From Dual 
        )
```

... the result is:

| ID | TC_NO | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tc_1 | PASS |
| 1 | tc_4 | PASS |
| 2 | tc_1 | FAIL |
| 2 | tc_4 | FAIL |